# Jquery check for existence of textbox and validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have 1 textbox for date, 1 dropdown list, 3 text box for input values.
Depends on the condition either 2 or 3 text boxes will be displayed, but text box for date and dropdownlist will
be common for both the conditions.
All of them including date textbox and dropdownlist are mandatory fields.
If the user clicks the button I need to check whether they entered all required fields or not, then I need to check
for results. If they missed to enter any of the required fields it should display the missed field with red border-color.

my code:

```
$("#btnCheck").click(function(){
//This "Validate" function will check and if any required field is missing will change the border-color of that element
Validate(Date, firstTextBox, secondTextBox, thirdTextBox, dropdownValue);
if (Date.length > 0 && firstTextBox.length > 0 && secondTextBox.length > 0 && dropdownValue != "") {
    //It will call my ajax function
}
});

function Validate(Date, firstTextBox, secondTextBox, thirdTextBox, dropdownValue) {
    $("#txtDate, #txt1, #txt2, #ddlValue").css("border-color", "");
    if (Date.length == 0) { $("#txtDate").css("border-color", "red"); }
    if (firstTextBox.length == 0) { $("#txt1").css("border-color", "red"); }
    if (secondTextBox.length == 0) { $("#txt2").css("border-color", "red"); }
    if (dropdownValue == "") { $("#ddl").css("border-color", "red"); }
}
```

My req:

If the 3rd text box is present on my web page, then I need to validate the input for that 3rd textbox and
if the user entered input then it should call the ajax function.

Any help in this will lot helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you determine if there are 4 or 5 fields to be passed to ajax?

Comment: While displaying page am checking a condition whether to display 3rd textbox or not. If it is displayed it should pass 5 values, otherwise 4 values

Comment: Couldn't you just validate the first four, pass all five variables to the server, and let the server decide if the fifth is present or absent, and only save the fifth variable if it's present?

Comment: In that case when I actually need to pass 5 values, and user entered only 4 values, do you want me to validate on the server side for 5 th value?

Comment: I think that is very reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put this rudimentary [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5v3Ph/2/) together with a simple validation.

If the input is not valid, the function stops and tells the user where the data are missing.

If the first four variables have valid data (validcheck = 'yyyy'), ALL FIVE variables would be passed to the server with the ajax, and the server will store the first four (all valid, therefore storable), and the fifth would be stored if it exists, if not, it would not be stored.

I'm not sure if this concept will work for you.

JS

```
var datevalue, compass, textone, texttwo, textthree;
var validcheck;
$('#clickme').on('click', function(){
                 datevalue = $('#date').val();
                 compass = $('#firstoption').val();
                 textone = $('#firsttext').val();
                 texttwo = $('#secondtext').val();
                 textthree = $('#thirdtext').val();
                 validateme(datevalue, compass, textone, texttwo, textthree);
});

function validateme(one, two, three, four, five)
{
  if( one.length < 2 )
    {
     $('#date').css('border', '2px solid red');
     $('#date2').html('Required');
     validcheck = 'n';
     }
      else
    { validcheck = 'y'; }
  if( two.length < 1 )
  {
   $('#firstoption').css('border', '2px solid red');
   $('#firstoption2').html('Required');
   validcheck = validcheck + 'n';
   }
    else { validcheck = validcheck  + 'y'; }
  if( three.length < 1 )
  {
   $('#firsttext').css('border', '2px solid red');
   $('#firsttext2').html('Required');
   validcheck = validcheck + 'n';
   }
    else { validcheck = validcheck + 'y'; }

  if( four.length < 1 )
  {
   $('#secondtext').css('border', '2px solid red');
   $('#secondtext2').html('Required');
   validcheck = validcheck + 'n';
   }
    else { validcheck = validcheck  + 'y'; }

  if( validcheck == 'yyyy' )
    {
     //pass one, two, three, four, five to server with ajax
     alert('pass 5 variables to ajax');
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check and let you know.